# document.evaluate won't work from content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, xpath, google-chrome-extension, document.evaluate

```
var allTags = document.evaluate("//*[contains(@src,'"+imgSrc+"')]", document, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
```

This is the code that gives errors, it gives:

```
Uncaught Error: TYPE_ERR: DOM XPath Exception 52
```

Could someone tell me what the problem is?

Comment: What is the value of `imgSrc`?

Comment: It's a path. For testing purposes, let's say that it is `http://localhost/logo.png`. I ended up using jQuery for this, but I'd still like to get an answer to this, since jQuery isn't exactly lightweight.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a precise answer, but I can guess and give a workaround.

First the work around: change `UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE` to a type that don't create a snapshot(unless you need it that way) and returns multiple nodes like `UNORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE`(or `ANY_TYPE`).

And my guess: After reading the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/NOTE-DOM-Level-3-XPath-20040226/DOM3-XPath.html#xpath-XPathEvaluator-evaluate) it say for this function 'TYPE_ERR: Raised if the result cannot be converted to return the specified type.'. It may be the case it can't allocate the resources to create a snapshot or something like this(the workaround assumes that).

Edit:

The real problem is most likely not the call to `document.evaluate` is that in your code you do `allTags.iterateNext` and this call expects `allTags` to be a *_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE and not a *_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, using `allTags.snapshotItem` don't cause an error to be thrown. I wrote a sample at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4r3PS/2/), it changes the borders after 2 seconds using the call to evaluate in your question and iterate over the elements in the proper way.

Comment: Well, I need it like that, as I need to be able to access the original object properties.

Comment: You always could perform a deep copy(https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.cloneNode) of the nodes returned and store the copies in an array.

Comment: Does that allow me to change the original object properties?